# Chimney Cap Sizing

Tags: fireplace, chimney

I am looking for help with finding a chimney cap that fits the double layer flue on my chimney. See below for an image with measurements. All of the chimney cap sizes online seem to have one measurement (I.e. 8” for an 8” flue), but my 8” flue flares to ~10.5” and is double layered so I’m having a hard time navigating the products. Could someone help me find a compatible chimney cap? I have also included an image of the existing chimney cap (super rusty). For reference, this house was built in 1986.

Image with measurements: https://imgur.com/oJDmZDY

Zoomed out image: https://imgur.com/LpJorV2

Original chimney cap: https://imgur.com/irfq5cG

Comment: Picture says *Crown cap hole is ~15"*... So a 16x16? The gap between the outer flue and the crown probably shouldn't be able to let sparks back down.

Answer (score 1):

Many caps must be custom made.

We recently had all the caps replaced on the 96 units in our condo complex.  It was discovered that there was 8 different sizes even though there are only 2 different chimney types.

The bottom line is that there are many different sized factors.  For this reason you may be better served to contact a metal shop to custom bend a cap to suit your needs.

We had them made from stainless, an idea if it fits your budget. None will need replacement for about 50 years.